# is there an upper bound for damage reduction with armor and resistances?

Tags: diablo-iii

It seems that the damage reduction curves for armor and resistance gain are not linear, so at some point it'll reach a limit.  What is this limit for armor and resistance?  How much armor will I need for 95% reduction (just counting armor reduction, not from anything else such as the barbarian/monk passive reduction of 30%).  Is it possible to have enough armor for 95% reduction?

Comment: Well I know the armour cap is 38k, but I'm not sure what kind of reduction that translates to or what the caps are for other forms of DR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an upper bound for damage reduction... it's 100%.

However:

1. It's not possible to reach 100% damage reduction.
2. Effective HP (as a percentage of 'base HP') *is* linear with respect to resistance and armor (they're calculated separately, then multiplied). At level 60, every 3000 armor (or 300 resistance) gives you +100% EHP.
3. It may be possible to reach 95% reduction just from armor, but it's not a good idea. You'd need 57000 armor (which probably isn't possible even with BiS +armor gear). However, to get 95% DR from resistance and armor *combined*, you need about 10400 armor and 1040 resist all, which is nearly 1/3rd the item budget.

See [this D3 forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149150485) for much more detail.